# Prompt to turn on device GPS in PWA

Tags: android, ionic-framework, geolocation, gps, progressive-web-apps

After going through tons of literature related to Geolocation in PWA, I am not sure whether this is possible but **is there a mechanism for prompting the user to turn on device GPS in PWA?**

What I am hoping to do is a solution similar to https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/location-accuracy/.

While the decision to turn on GPS is with the user, a prompt will help them to easily make the decision. I have gone through lot of tutorials and docs but haven't found anything yet. Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You can show a prompt that explains the benefits if you activate the geolocation, and if the user agrees there to make the request for geolocation in the background.

If your intention is to implement it on the web, you could check this plugin also that is compatible with Native and PWA.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/

More info: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/user-location/

Comment: The ionic native geolocation plugin allows listening to location feed from OS but it does not have option to prompt the user to turn on GPS. I guess the feature is not yet available in web.